# Best way to parse JSON-like file using awk/sed

Tags: json, bash, parsing, awk, sed

I have a file which contents are like the following:

```
{application_name, [
    {settings, [
        {generic_1, [
            {key_1, "value"},
            {key_2, 1},
            {key_3, [something, other]}
        ]},
        {generic_2, [
            {key_1, "value"},
            {key_3, [something, other]}
        ]},
        {{generic_2, specific_1}, [
            {key_3, [entirely, different]}
        ]},
    ]}
]}
```

Now I'm looking for a way to parse this using awk or sed (or something else). What I need is to be able to specify a key, and then get the "blockname" returned.

f.e. if I want all settings for `key_3` returned as follows:

```
generic_1 [something, other]
generic_2 [something, other]
specific_1 [entirely, different]
```

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: The best way? Don't use `awk` or `sed`, which are geared toward line-oriented data, not structured formats like JSON.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution for how to parse JSON data with sed or awk is... not to do that with sed or awk. They aren't designed for it.

Use a tool that understands JSON like

1. perl
2. python
3. ruby
4. javascript
5. [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
6. Just about anything else

Using anything like `sed` or `awk` on this is going to be fragile (at best).

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with Etan that this is a job for another tools.
This is an `gnu awk` approach (due to multiple characters in RS), not a complete solution.

```
awk -v RS="generic_[0-9]" 'NR==1 {f=RT;next} {$1=$1;n=split($0,a,"[][]");if (a[1]~/}/) {split(a[1],b,"[ }]");f=b[2]};printf "%s [",f;for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if (a[i]~/key_3/) print a[i+1]"]";f=RT}' file
generic_1 [something, other]
generic_2 [something, other]
specific_1 [entirely, different]
```

Or some more readable:

```
awk -v RS="generic_[0-9]" '
NR==1 {
    f=RT
    next} 
    {
    $1=$1
    n=split($0,a,"[][]")
    if (a[1]~/}/) {
        split(a[1],b,"[ }]")
        f=b[2]}
    printf "%s [",f
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        if (a[i]~/key_3/)
            print a[i+1]"]"
            f=RT
    }' file
```